# How do I disable the stock Gallery app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android, gallery, default-applications, sony-xperia-active

I just downloaded QuickPic and so far it's all good and fast. It has more features than the stock Gallery including the ability to include / exclude certain folders from view. For this reason, I don't need/want the stock Gallery app to still be open-able. Is there a way to hide it from the list of applications from the grid of icons? I want QuickPic to catch all tasks that Gallery does and at the same time I want to prevent others (namely, friends who borrow my phone from time to time) from opening the Gallery app.

Note:
My phone (Xperia Active) is not rooted and I believe rooting it will void my 1 year warranty with Sony.

Comment: If you're rooted, you could remove it, though I don't know if the system depends on it on your device.  If you're worried about your friends though, you ought to encrypt sensitive things or not lend them your device; this won't cut it.

Comment: Well, while I do plan on rooting it, I wouln't want to void my warranty especially since I just got it late last week. I'm also going to taking encryption into consideration. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an alternative launcher like [Launcher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher) / [ADW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher) / [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) etc. All of these have options for hiding apps from the app drawer.

Unfortunately, the Gallery app will still appear in SHARE and SEND TO menus in various apps. No way around that. If you would rather certain folders remain invisible to the Gallery app, [place a blank file](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-prevent-a-directory-from-being-scanned-by-android-gallery/) named `.nomedia` in the folder to keep it from being displayed in the Gallery. Unsure if Quickpic will also have same functionality.

Comment: I was already aware of the .nomedia trick, I just wanted to know if there were ways to hide or disable the Gallery app so that noone would be able to use it.

Comment: You could use a password protection app so no one can use the gallery without entering the correct pwd. Example - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidpassword.core

Comment: Wow @Sparx, that is rather nice. Do you know of an application that does the same but instead, just prevents the app from launching and not showing some password protected sign? Freeware or paid will do.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro can hide individual files, photos and apps. Try it - fair warning - I don't use it. Always make backups of your data and device.

Answer (score 4):

Stock Gallery is a system app which can't be disabled if you are not rooted. Titanium Backup Pro can freeze it, but only if it gets root access.

Rooting will violate your warranty, but you can always get your warranty back after un-rooting device. There's no way for anyone to catch you after that. In case, you are unable to find an un-rooting method, you can flash original firmware. Its the ultimate solution.
So, you can go ahead to root your device.

Comment: When I flash it, does it mean I have to find a specific app to do the flashing on a certain device? -> is a rooting newb

Comment: @Shedo Worth a new question... well, there are many methods of flashing: Over USB using desktop software, using android app on rooted device, from recovery mode (partial flashing)..

Comment: @Shedo By the way, rooting tools generally provide a way to un-root...

Comment: I think I'm going to pass the rooting idea for now. I'm still uneasy with all the rooting shenanigans and I don't see lots of help for mac users with regards to rooting Android phones.

Comment: @Shedo Its alright.. but, I answered what you've asked: How to **Disable**... After freezing, Gallery won't drain your memory and battery... Its an always running app.